# MintMenu recent documents

Tags: mint, document

I install the MintMenu and i am starting to like it but i miss a feature i liked in the ubuntu "application - places - system" menu.

I cannot find my recent documents

it is possible to add/show the "recent documents" in the MintMenu?

i did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/mintmenu && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mintmenu
```

i am using ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried right-clicking on the menu icon, selecting "Preferences", then in the "Options" tab checking "Show recent documents plugin"?